# My question got downvoted because I was asking if a feature existed. What gives?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was hoping to get some post-mortem advice on how I could have phrased this question better:

[How can Boost be used to achieve C++14-style auto return types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321237/can-i-use-boost-to-get-c14-auto-return-types)

I wasn't able to find a solution to a problem so I documented the code that produced the problem, outlined what I think the solution might be, and asked if something like this existed.

I'm fairly confident, having [read the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), that this question complies with SO rules, but nonetheless I received a lot of downvotes and this question is on the verge of being closed on the basis that it is asking for a recommendation.

Feeling good about myself for having asked a compliant question is nice but it isn't much use when my question is getting mob-lynched and given that, at the end of the day, the real reason I'm on this website is to learn and participate.

So, having hopefully taken a peek at this question, could you suggest how I might have written it differently to not attract so much negative attention? I did not find the comments provided by others to be particularly useful, and was of the view that they were basically just stating the obvious, albeit in a negative light.

Comment: Can't comment on the boost topic at hand here, but the question itself seems reasonably answerable (if positive or not) and well-presented (in comparison to all the daily actually closeworthy stuff). The question title though "Can I ..." is likely to be misinterpreted as asking for trivial/opinion/one-liner posts. In such cases just presupposing a technical solution with "How can boost do ..." often sounds better.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773 _'Almost all yes/no questions... should be edited into a question that isn't really asking for just a yes/no, it should be asking to explain something. (Even if it has a yes/no in there somewhere.) Note that just adding "Explain" at the end isn't really a good way to go about this; you should refactor the question on a more fundamental level...'_

Comment: @mario, thanks! Noted and edited.

Comment: Everybody is free to downvote questions they don't like. Could have been based on the tone of your question (much better after the edit, BTW), or anything else. I don't think the close votes are justified, though. This looks like a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: QA site for Software Recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com (not that your question is actually asking for recommendations anyway, but just wanted to mention this site)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul "*your question is actually asking for recommendations*" could you explain why this is the case?

Comment: @Arman: I wrote *"Not that X"* which means *"I know that X is not true"*.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul sorry, I read "note" instead of "not". Need more coffee..

Comment: you got 8 downvotes, but 42 upvotes. The downvoters complained about the question, you fixed it, in the end the community consensus decided and everyone is better off, how is this a bad thing?

Comment: Presumably the upvotes came after the question was posted on Meta.

Comment: In general, if you don't get a positive response to your question, edit it or let it close/get blown away and re-ask it with more detail. Upvoting the question after the fact isn't helping anything.

Comment: @serakfalcon it's not. It's a good thing. I'm glad I came to MSO because it really shed some light on how I can phrase my questions better. Clearly it's paid off.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some people might consider the style of your question a bit too informal. It makes it sound slightly unprofessional and that may confuse the issue at hand. That said, the question itself seems perfectly valid to me - I can't see a reason to downvote or close it.

As for the *"asking for a recommendation"* part, I do not believe that it is a valid concern in this case. Every single question on SO is asking for some kind of recommendation, based on the experience of the other members. It's *software/product recommendations* specifically that are no longer considered on-topic...

Comment: Ah, thanks I hadn't thought of that. It's disappointing that people respond negatively to the way I communicate naturally, but I'll try to be more professional in my question style in future.

Comment: @Arman: I can't be certain that was the real reason - I am no C++ expert. Still, a potentially careless reviewer would see an informally phrased question of the "Does this exist?" variety and would assume that the poster didn't even bother using Google before posting...

Comment: @Arman - Do you still need an answer to that question? I can't provide one, but if you edit the question you might have another shot at getting one.

Comment: @misterManSam yes, I still haven't found a solution. I'll make the question more formal.

Comment: I disagree with the "every single question on SO is asking for some kind of recommendation" part.  There's a difference between a recommendation and a solution, which lies in the question itself: a solution is something that directly solves a problem.  A recommendation is a post stating *which* solution to choose, and is inherently opinion-based.

Comment: @Joe While I agree not every single questions asks for a recommendation, every answer is technically _recommending_ a solution. Because the answerer believes that is the solution, but the OP is free to choose which solution to use, or some solutions may not work for the OP. So both points are partially correct.

Comment: I don't agree.  I've posted more than one solution that I didn't consider the superior solution for the task at hand (either because of the asker's specifics or because the solution was too hard to be worth it in most cases), but was worth posting because other users with the same question but slightly different needs might find it useful.  A solution is just that, a solution: the recommendation to use it might be a given, but the solution is the important part.  The votes determine what solution (if more than one exists) is recommended by the community.

Comment: @Joe _"the recommendation to use it might be a given"_ That's what I meant. Even if you don't feel it's the best, the solution is implicitly recommended when you post it as an answer. I didn't mean you're saying it's best, just it's been recommended as a possible way to do it. :)

Answer (score 6):

Your question looks fine to me.

I'd say you just got unlucky and caught the attention of silly people. In a community as large as ours, where understanding of SO's nature is extremely rare, it happens.